# Grails. Select tag

Tags: grails

I am using 2 select tags. Their content can be modified inside the web page(via javascript). 
By default grails will take only the selected option (or all selected options if multiple is enabled) and pass it to the controller.
How could I pass to the controller all the available rows from a select box ?

Comment: you want to have an onchange event, which sends both selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a secondary hidden list which has all elements selected.  Then this list will get sent as well?

Or I guess you could maintain a hidden form element containing some sort of delimited list of names (but then you might get problems choosing a delimiter and escaping the values)